# kindle fire custom url how to?

Tags: kindle-fire, custom-url

Im creating a android app need to support custom url. like myapp://
It's work in the other android devices. But Kindle Fire tested not work.
I just add the code below to AndroidManifest.xml to make the custom url work. for the Kindle Fire do I missing anything?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working if you click on a link, but you cannot type into the Kindle Fire browser because it will always revert to search for it.